# How to use Keras Tokenizer for Characters?

Tags: keras, tokenize

For the sequence labeling task, my training data and labels look like following :

```
train_data=[['p','l','a','y','s']

train_labels=[['<p>','<l>','<a>','<y*>','<s*>']]
```

How can I use tokenizer and generate representation for each sequence in my data. The traditional tokenizer ignores labels such as `<p>`. It only creates vocabulary of standard characters.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, this should do the trick. If I'm mistaken let me know so I can edit the answer accordingly

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tk = Tokenizer(num_words=None, char_level=True)
tk.fit_on_texts(texts)
```

Where `texts` is where the actual texts are.

You can check the vocabulary using

```
tk.word_index
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in that case it generates Indexes for <, p and > differently. what I want is there should be only one Index for '<p>' and so on.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are actually trying to do? What is the problem you're trying to solve? I'm not really sure why you'd want to tokenize the labels. Better if you can do that in the actual answer and not here in the comments. I'll update the answer accordingly